# Extracting JSON from PHP on Android

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I have tried and tried this and can't seem to get to the bottom of it. Here is the PHP code

```
$query = "SELECT `title` FROM `c2torsdb`.`pE_vacancies` WHERE active=1 LIMIT 2";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
/* create one master array of the records */
$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    }
  }
  /* output in necessary format */
  if($format == 'json') {
    header('Content-type: application/json, charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($posts);
  }
```

And here is my code snippet

```
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

    //JSONArray innerobj = object.getJSONArray("post");
    String name = object.getString("title");
    //String name = name1.getString(0);

    Log.v("isurgeon", name);

    //String name = object.getString("posts");
    //String verion = object.getString("version");
    textView.setText(name + " - ");
```

Here is the JSON output from the PHP script:

```
[{"post":{"title":"Property Litigation Assistant Solicitor"}},{"post":{"title":"Trusts and Probate Practitioner"}}]
```

I just want the 'title'.

Comment: What is the problem? Does it crash (log cat please), or what? Just a guess: your JSON response is an array, so `new JSONObject(jsonResult)` can not work. Use `new JSONArray(jsonResult)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be honest, I am not familiar with android but I know JSON.  If I were to take your JSON output and place it into javascript like this:

```
var abc = [{"post":{"title":"Property Litigation Assistant Solicitor"}},{"post":{"title":"Trusts and Probate Practitioner"}}]
```

I would get the 1st title by doing this:

```
abc[0].title
```

You need to select the nth element of the returned json object THEN get the title.

Answer (score 0):

Bill's right - the way your JSON is outputted there, everything is enclosed in an array

Android imo has really good native handling for JSON Objects / arrays so if you simply do

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);

JSONObject object = jsonArray[0];
```

everything should work fine